# Celery subtask which uses sqlalchemy session raises UnboundExecutionError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, celery

I have a celery task which triggers off some subtasks under it. It runs those subtasks non-async.

```
@shared_task
def task_update_all_customers(customer_ids=()):
    job = group(
        task_update_customer.subtask((cust_id, ))
        for cust_id in customer_ids
    )
    result = job.apply()
    all_completed = result.ready()
    return all_completed


@shared_task
def task_update_customer(customer_id):
    with session_scope() as session:
        num = (
            session.query(SomeModel)
            .filter(SomeModel.customer_id == customer_id)
            .statement.with_only_columns([func.count()]).order_by(None).scalar()
        )
        print(num)
```

For some reason when subtask `def task_update_customer` executes it raises on the sqlalchemy query with:

> UnboundExecutionError`: This AnnotatedSelect object is not directly
>   bound to a Connection or Engine.Use the .execute() method of a
>   Connection or Engine to execute this construct.

However I'm using `session_scope`, and I also have a full integration test of "task_update_customer" which works as expected.

Here's `session_scope` implementation: https://pastebin.com/p7DRvkFs

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Changing my query to this "fixed" it

```
    num = (
        session.query(SomeModel)
        .filter(SomeModel.customer_id == customer_id)
        .count()
    )
```